# (1) table mytable has no column named number in "INSERT INTO mytable(number,name,email) VALUES (?,?,?)"

Tags: javascript, android-studio

If I delete the line " **"number" + "text"** ", the code works.

Error:

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) table mytable has no column named number in "INSERT
> INTO mytable(number,name,email) VALUES (?,?,?)"
>
> E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting number=866454 name=TEST email=TEST
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table mytable has no column
> named number (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO
> mytable(number,name,email) VALUES (?,?,?)

```
String name = text_name.getText().toString();
String email = text_email.getText().toString();
String number = text_phone.getText().toString();

SQLiteDatabase data_base = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                    ContentValues container = new ContentValues();
                    container.put("name", name);
                    container.put("email", email);
                    container.put("number", number);
                    long rowID = data_base.insert("mytable", null, container);
                    Log.d("Log: ", "row inserted, ID = " + rowID);
```

AND

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                    + "id" + "integer primary key autoincrement,"
                    + "name" + "text,"
                    + "email" + "text,"
                    + "number" + "TEXT UNIQUE"
                    + ");");
        }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: You're not adding spaces between column names and type when creating them. This would result in your columns to be named `nametext`, `emailtext` and `numberTEXT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you split up your text and concatinated with a +, but it hid the error.

```
"create table mytable ("
                + "id" + "integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "name" + "text,"
                + "email" + "text,"
                + "number" + "TEXT UNIQUE"
```

renders into this:

```
create table mytable (idinteger primary key 
autoincrement,nametext,emailtext,numberTEXT 
UNIQUE)
```

You need to add spaces and for code clarity get rid of the unnecessary concatenation.
I would do this:

```
"create table mytable ("
                + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "name text,"
                + "email text,"
                + "number TEXT UNIQUE"
```